# How to create and use a gridview for an Android Application

Tags: android, xml, gridview, android-gridview

I am developing an Android Application and since I do not know XML, I have some problems about XML gridview.

In my application, a query is sent to the server and according to server's response i need to list some data. But as I stated, I do not know how to do. As you can guess, data size can differ from query to query, so i need to have an gridview with unfixed size.

Can you help, by sending an example code, or by explaining how can I list data on my application.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See [Hello GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) for a tutorial on using a `GridView`.  A `GridView` has an unfixed size by default.